# How does boost program_options work?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

The weird thing to me is, that boost's *options_description* uses multi-line code without backslash or semicolon or comma. I did a little research, but found nothing.

(Code taken from [official boost's tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html)):

```
int opt;
po::options_description desc("Allowed options"); 
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ("optimization"   , po::value<int>(&opt)->default_value(10), "optimization level")
    ("include-path,I ", po::value< vector<string> >()          , "include path")
    ("input-file     ", po::value< vector<string> >()          , "input file") ;
```

How is it implemented? Is it a macro?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a bit of a strange syntax in C++ but if you're familiar with JS (for example), you might be aware of the concept of *method chaining*. This is a bit like that.

`add_options()` returns an object with `operator()` defined. The second line calls `operator()` on the object returned by the first line. The method returns a reference to the original object, so you can keep calling `operator()` many times in a row.

Here's a simplified version of how it works:

```
#include <iostream>

class Example
{
public:
    Example & operator()(std::string arg) {
        std::cout << "added option: " << arg << "\n";
        return *this;
    }
    Example & add_options() {
        return *this;        
    }
};

int main()
{
    Example desc;
    desc.add_options()
        ("first")
        ("second")
        ("third");
    return 0;
}
```

As pointed out by [gbjbaanb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014250/how-does-boost-program-options-work#comment38898201_25014408) in the comments, this is actually quite similar to how chaining of assignments `a = b = c = 0` works for classes. It is also similar to the behaviour that is pretty much taken for granted when using `ostream::operator<<`: you expect to be able to do `std::cout << "string 1" << "string 2" << "string 3"`.

Comment: in much the same way as you can write `a = b = c = 0;`

Answer (score 7):

The add_options() method returns object that implements the "()" operator and the () operator in turn returns the same object. See the following code:

```
class Example
{
public:
    Example operator()(string arg)
    {
        cout << arg << endl;
        return Example();
    }
    Example func(string arg)
    {
        operator()(arg);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Example ex;
    ex.func("Line one")
           ("Line two")
           ("Line three");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the way it works.

Comment: Your example is not great.

Comment: @Gall: I didn't claim my example is great.

Comment: Ok, but you could do something proper like Tom Fenech ones.

Comment: @Gall: I agree, but this is a simple one to demonstrate the use of () operator repeatedly.